# Reference Error | javascript

Tags: javascript

1. Can anyone explain how below code works in JavaScript or any other programming language.
2. What the below referencing is called.

---

```
var a=5;
var a=b;
b=10;
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
10 // value of a returned
10 // value of b returned
```

or

```
var a=5, b;
var a=b;
b=10;
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Both returns value as 10. Why is the value of **a** is assigned to **10** and how?

Comment: What have you assigned `b` beforehand?

Comment: where does your b came from?

Comment: b is not defined.

Comment: So then, what's the question?

Comment: why the value of "a" is changed to 10.

Comment: It can't be... @AshishsinghRawat, your code throws a ReferenceError.

Comment: Could you please provide some live example?

Comment: This is just a exercise. below is the piece of code.

`var a=5, b;`
`var a=b;`
`b=10;`
`console.log(a);`
`console.log(b);`

Comment: I need something to verify this is happening, maybe a screenshot? In your second example `a` would be undefined even outside strict mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will never work.

It will show `b` is not defined in javascript.

Comment: b is not defined. but this code works without using the keyword "use strict"

Comment: I was wondering, why hoisting isn't playing it's role. Can you please elaborate on how hoisting fits in the given piece of code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

```
var a=5;
var b=a;  //changed this from var a=b to var b=a. this is important
b=10;
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

line one declares var a, it equals to five. 
line two declares var b, it equals to a, which is five. on ur code u said var a is b (b is never declared)
line three says var b is ten. 
then u just logs them.

or if u mean this

```
var a=5;
var b=a;  //changed this from var a=b to var b=a. this is important
a=10;
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

then it's basically the same thing except on line 3, u change value of a to 10. u would think that var b's value will also be 10 but you need to say b=a AGAIN after that